# Modularizing Socket.io with Express 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I'm trying to modularize my application files and I'm having problems with **Socket.io**. I would like to use the io inside my `routes.js`. Something like this:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var io     = require('./sockets/my-io');

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  io.emit('request-detected');
});

module.exports = router;
```

But I can't do, because the socket.io needs the app server, and when I'm inside the routes.js file, the app server is not listening or being exported yet.

Can you give me a solution, or any other approach to this problem?

Here's what I have, and if it's possible, I would like to keep the **file structure**:

app.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var routes = require('./routes');

/* ... */

app.use('/contacts', routes);

module.exports = app;
```

bin/www

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var app = require('../wallet');

var server = app.listen(port, function() {
  debug('Express is listening o port ' + port);
});
```

routes.js

```
var router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log('hey');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Why don't you just initialize socket.io in your main app.js file (where you create the server) and then you can put all the socket.io message handling code in a module and pass that module the initialize `io` instance in the constructor?

Comment: @GuilhermeRvCoelho Hi, I just asked same question yesterday(and get several downvote in a row) before I found this post, I wonder did you figure out a better way to solve this problem?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by passing the io variable to your routes module.

bin/www

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var app = require('./app');

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Express is listening on port 3000');
}); // start the server

var socket = require('./socket')(server); // require socket.io code
var routes = require('./routes')(socket); // require routes

app.use('/', routes);
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('views engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/');

module.exports = app;
```

socket.js

```
var socketio = require('socket.io');
function init(server) {
    var io = socketio(server);
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log("socket connected");
        socket.on('newEvent', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
    return io;
}

module.exports = init;
```

routes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var route = express.Router();

function init(io) {
    route.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.render('index.ejs', {});
        setTimeout(function() {io.emit('newEvent', {message: "Hi from the server"})}, 2000);
    });
    return route;
}
module.exports = init;
```

The code above worked for me. However, I'm not sure why you want to do that.

Inside the router, you still have full control of what you want to send to the user via html, so you can just add the data to the html directly.
The idea of socket.io is that you can send data between the client and back once he has loaded the html and established a connection to your server with socket.io.

As you can see in the `routes.js`, I had to add a timeout to the emit. This is because the socket event will be emit before the browser has reloaded the page. In my case the browser logged the event and then immediately refreshed, losing the data you just sent.

Another problem is that you don't know anything about the socket of the client that is requesting the page because he hasn't connected yet. This means that calling `io.emit()` will send the event to all connected sockets.

As I said, this really depends on what exactly you want to do.

EDIT:

Instead of updating your contacts using ajax, you can do that with socket.io.

socket.js

```
var socketio = require('socket.io');
function init(server) {
    var io = socketio(server);
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log("socket connected");
        socket.on('newContact', function (data, callback) {
            // add data.contactName to db

            // after adding something, you use the callback to
            // send the added data back to the client

            // callback(newContact);
        });
    });
    return io;
}

module.exports = init;
```

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var socket = io();
    // call this emit when the user wants to add a contact
    socket.emit('newContact', {contactName: name}, function(newContact) {
        // here you will get the result from the server and you can
        // update the html with jquery for example
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I want to that, because I want to emit data to all my pages, not only the page I requested (I'm using a Single Page Application approach)

Comment: Your solutiion is good and it works perfectly. However, I would like to keep that file structure: (bin/www, app.js, routes.js)

Comment: You said that you want to emit data to all your pages. What exactly do you mean? Do you want to emit to all the pages of the single page app (for example /index /profile etc...), or do you want to emit to all users connected to your page?

Comment: I have a contacts app with two pages: All Contacts and Add Contacts. When I create a new contact (via ajax) the All Contacts page doesn't refresh the contacts (because I'm in a SPA approach) unless I force-reload it (but I don't wanna do this). So, what I'm trying to do is: 1. Send a Post request to create a new contact. 2. Emit a 'contact-added'. 3. Listen to the 'contact-added' on the All Contacts page and refresh the contacts. I thought socket.io would be the best way to do this.

Comment: Socket.io is great to do that. Are you using Angularjs?

Comment: I'm using Polymer and Webcomponents (the application is just for practice)

Comment: Ok. I don't know about those. But I think the idea on how to do it remains the same: You establish a socket connection after a client loads your app. Now you have a "direct channel" to the server, so you don't need to send ajax requests anymore. You can simply send the new contact to the server using socket.io. I will update my answer with a small example.

Comment: I'm dealing with differente types of requests (POST, GET, DELETE and PUT). Isn't there a problem to use the socket.io to all of these? But anyway, your answers helped me. I think what I'm going to do is, from the client, create the new contact via AJAX and also emit an event to the server. This way, I can listen to the event and tell the other pages to reload the contacts list.

Comment: Yeah you can do that too. I'm glad I could help

Comment: If you want to add socket functionality to the router I highly reccomend the solution by Logan Tegman http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29872317/express-4-routes-using-socket-io

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly ,maybe you can try this way.

in your `routes.js` file

```
var app    = require('./app');
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io     = require('./sockets/my-io')(server);
var route  = app.Router();
```

in your `app.js` file

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port,function(){ 
    console.log('server on port ' + port)
})
```