# Express 4 Routes Using Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js

Having a rough time adding Socket.io in my Express 4 Routes. In my routes/index.js I have:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post('/message', function(req, res) {
  console.log("Post request hit.");
  // res.contentType('text/xml');
  console.log(appjs);
  io.sockets.emit("display text", req);
  // res.send('<Response><Sms>'+req.body+'</Sms></Response>');
});

module.exports = router;
```

but io is undefined. I have seen several examples of how to do this, but none that worked for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `var io = require("socket.io")(app)` ? (Where app is your http server)

Comment: in my app.js file at root

Answer (score 12):

You need to pass your socket.io variable to the router module so that it has access. You could do this by wrapping your module in a function call.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
var returnRouter = function(io) {
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
        res.render('index', {
            title: 'Express'
        });
    });

    router.post('/message', function(req, res) {
        console.log("Post request hit.");
        // res.contentType('text/xml');
        console.log(appjs);
        io.sockets.emit("display text", req);
        // res.send('<Response><Sms>'+req.body+'</Sms></Response>');
    });

    return router;
}

module.exports = returnRouter;
```

Then, whever you import this route you would call this function like: `require(./routefile)(io)`

Here's a good article about creating modules that require being passed a variable: [Node.Js, Require and Exports](http://openmymind.net/2012/2/3/Node-Require-and-Exports/)

Comment: By far the cleanest solution I've seen to add the socket functionality to the router! I had to search everywhere to find this! thx @LoganTegman

Comment: but the same doesn't work for get requests and only works for post requests

Comment: @NickPineda I dont see how, controller logic and route logic both inside same file. Sure

Comment: Pls help me, I have no idea why its not working. I have try so many time.

```
module.exports = function (io) {
  router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    const io = SocketIO()
    const data = req?.body?.data.message
    const room = req?.body?.data?.room

    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      console.log("Socket Running...")
      //   socket.to(room).emit("the_message", data)
      socket.emit("the_message", data)
    })

    return res.status(200).json({ data: req.body.data })
  })

  return router
}```
The log in io.on is not printing but when I log io,

Answer (score 3):

How about exploiting events? This could add an extra layer of self-awareness to the app, including socket messaging.

Since express's app() inherits from node's eventEmitter, I `app.emit('EVENT_NAME', payload)` at any point in my route handlers,
and then just handle that with `app.on('EVENT_NAME', function(payload){})`
with any logic available. I'm using it in my current setup.

Answer (score 1):

This is super old, but I was looking to do the same thing and didn't find a suitable answer. I came up with a good solution using `app.set('socketio', io)` and `req.app.get('socketio')` in my route.  I was then able to create a reference to the sender's socket in my route without using `io.on()`.

See the answer I added here for the code:

[Use socket.io inside a express routes file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856190/use-socket-io-inside-a-express-routes-file/57737798#57737798)