# Express socket.io routes does not POST

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am unable to do POST with socket in express route. Getting error `"Cannot POST /send"` Below my server code.

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));
app.use("/css", express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use("/js", express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


var aws_router = require('./routes/aws')(io);
var another_routes = require('./routes/another.js')(app);


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});


server.listen(8080);
```

In my **routes/aws.js** where I basically have database read/write

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var process = require('process');

var aws_router = function(io){

  router.post('/view', function(req, res) {
    //need to read from database
    var email = req.body.emailView;
    var paramsRead = {
        TableName: tableNameShopper,
        Key:{
            "email": email
        }
    };

    readFromTable(paramsRead).then((results) => {
        var objShopper = JSON.parse(results);
            if(results =="{}"){
          //nothing to do
          console.log("got null");
        }
        else{
          io.sockets.emit("viewdata", objShopper);
        }
        //res.json(request.objShopper)
      });

      res.sendFile(path.join(process.cwd() + '/view.html'));
  });
 return router;
} 

module.exports = aws_router;
```

I am able to do POST without socket.io but when I add the socket.io capability, I cant do POST. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29872317/express-4-routes-using-socket-io) example but doesn't help

What am I missing?

Comment: In `app.js`, `aws_router` is never hooked into your Express app.  You need `app.use(somePath, aws_router)`.

Answer (score 0):

You forget to return the router instance at the end of `aws_router` function:

```
var aws_router = function(io) {

    ...

    return router;
} 

module.exports = aws_router;
```

Also, you should tell express to use the created routing module `routes/aws.js` by adding this line:

```
app.use('/', aws_router);
```

Comment: I had `return router`; in the code but forgot to paste [see edit]. Once I add `app.use('/', aws_router);`, I get below error `TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined at Function.use`

Comment: you have to add `app.use('/', aws_router);` in the app.js file just after `var another_routes = require('./routes/another.js')(app);`

Comment: solved the problem in a different way. But the problem is different now. See this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48592536/express-route-socket-io-emit-data-not-captured-by-client