# Express route socket.io emit data not captured by client

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express

I am able to emit a socket in my ExpressJS route file. But that emitted data is not read by the client side javascript.

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));
app.use("/css", express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use("/js", express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.set('io', io);

var aws_router = require('./app/routes')(app);

server.listen(8080);
```

**app/routes.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var process = require('process');



var aws_router = function(app, io){

  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    //need to read from database
    var socketio = req.app.get('io');
      var objShopper = "hello"
      console.log(objShopper)
      socketio.emit("viewdata", objShopper);
      res.sendFile(path.join(process.cwd() + '/index.html'));
  });
  return router;
}

module.exports = aws_router;
```

The socket emit portion works fine, at least I see no error and output hello in the console. But when I try to read the emitted data from client side JS, I can't read it.

**client.js**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
    socket.on('viewdata', function (results) {
        console.log("read data");
        var objShopper = JSON.parse(results);
    });

});
```

`"read data"` is never shown in the console. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beside *jfreind00* answer, I think you should use `connection` event in the server side, it will be fired when the connection is established between client and server, and then you could emit data to the client:

```
var aws_router = function(app, io){

    app.get('/', function(req, res) {

        res.sendFile(path.join(process.cwd() + '/index.html'));
    });


    //make sure client and server are connected
    io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        var objShopper = "hello"
        console.log(objShopper)
        socketio.emit("viewdata", objShopper);
    });


    return router;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a timing issue.  You're trying to send to the socket before it's connected.  Here's the sequence of events:

1. Browser requests http://yourdomain/ from your server.
2. Your express route for `/` gets the request.
3. You get the `io` instance and do `io.emit()`.
4. Then you send index.html to satisfy the browser request.
5. The browser parses the resulting file
6. Browser runs your Javascript which makes a socket.io connection to your server.

Hopefully you can see that step 6 happens long after step 3 or put another way, step 3 happens before the page that is currently being requested even has a socket.io connection to your server.  Thus, when you do `io.emit()` and it iterates through all current connections to send the message to all of them, the page that is currently being requested is not in that list because it's connection has not been made yet.  Heck the page with the Javascript to make the connection hasn't even been sent to the browser yet.

---

Data that is known at the time the page is being requests should just be put into the page.  There's no socket.io connection yet so you can't send it there.  If you want it to be in the page, send it in the page.

If you don't want to put it in the initial page (for some reason), then you can let the page load and run and have the Javascript in the page request the data from your server via an Ajax call or when your Javascript connects to your server with socket.io and the server sees the incoming socket.io connection, it can send the data then (the timing will now be correct since the socket.io connection is established at this point).

Comment: @nad - Any data that is known at the time the page is requested should be put in the page itself.  Or, if you really want to get it separately, then let the client Javascript load and run and then you can either request data from your server via an Ajax call or when the server sees you connect with socket.io, it can send you data over socket.io then.

Comment: @nad - Did this answer your question?