# Pass sockets.io from express server file to route file

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I would use sockets in a separate route file .

I'm using the method mentioned in this answer : [Express 4 Routes Using Socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29872317/express-4-routes-using-socket-io)

I have copied exactly the same logic. In server file  :

```
var http = require("http");
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var firebase = require("firebase");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var port = process.env.app_port || 8080; // set our port
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var server = app.listen(port);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
var routerProj = require("./routes/routes")(io);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT ,DELETE');

  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,*");
  next();
});
var config = {
  .... DB Configuration ....
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var serviceAccount = require("./ServiceAcountKey.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://datatable-18f93.firebaseio.com"
});
io.on("connection", function (client) {
  console.log("Un client est connecté !");
  //routerProj(client);
});
app.use("/v1", routerProj, function (req) {
  //Create HTTP server and listen on port 8000 for requests

});
```

My connection socket is working and the console.log runs in terminal

**routes.js** file

```
var express = require("express"); // call express
var router = express.Router(); // get an instance of the express Router
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var returnRouter = function (client) {

  router.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // do logging
    client.on('save-message', function (socket) { console.log("heheyy") })
  });
  router
    .route("/")
    .get(function (req, res, err) {

      // Get a database reference to our posts
      var db = admin.database();
      var ref = db.ref("/");

      // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
      ref.once("value", function (snapshot) {
        var list = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function (elem) {
          list.push(elem.val());
        })
        list = JSON.stringify(list);
        //list = JSON.parse(list)

        console.log(err);
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(list))

        res.send(list);


      }, function (errorObject) {
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
        res.status(500).send(errorObject.code);
      });
    });

  router
    .route("/")
    .post(function (req, res, err) {
      console.log(req.body);
      // Get a database reference to our posts
      var db = admin.database();
      var ref = db.ref("/");

      ref.push(
        {
          "text": req.body.text
        }

      );

    });
  return router;
}
module.exports = returnRouter;
```

save-message is emit in Angular when my arr is running :

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.socket.emit('save-message', { room: "hello" });
  }
```

Save-message event is not getting read neither the routes file, In my angular application services does not get data from routes. and console.log in get and post routes does not work.

My question is how to get sockets working in a reparate file ?

Answer (score 0):

You should move the socket.io listener outside of the express `use` route. It's not really clear why you would want it there as it will register a new listener every time someone makes a request to your `v1` endpoint.

You likely aren't seeing the messages because the listener does not register until someone makes a request to the `v1` endpoint and the client already sent its message.

```
var returnRouter = function (client) {

    // do logging
    client.on('save-message', function (socket) { 
        console.log("heheyy");
    });

    ...
};
```

Comment: I'll test it in few hours, but is this the reason why routes does not trigger ?